# Problems with pyspotify

Tags: python, spotify, spotify-app

I have a problem in my attempt to make my first spotify app. I'm on a raspberry pi, running Arch.

I have my `__main__.py` and my `spotify_appkey.key` in a directory and i run it by `[root@RPI]# python2 __main__.py`

The code in `__main__.py` looks like this:

```
import spotify
print "1"
session = spotify.Session()
print "2"
try:
    session.login('myUsername', 'myPassword')
    print "3"
except IOError as e:
    print "error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
```

This gives me this output:

```
1
2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Reading on this [link](http://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/quickstart/#creating-a-session), I've tried this as well:

```
import spotify
print "1"
session = spotify.Session()
print "2"
config = spotify.Config()
print "3"
try:
    session.login('myUsername', 'myPassword')
    print "4"
except IOError as e:
    print "error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
```

which gives me this:

```
1
2
Traceback ..... yada yada ...
    File "__main__.py" ... yada yada...
        config = spotify.Config()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Config'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you're using an old version of pyspotify? It looks like the Config class was added fairly recently: https://github.com/mopidy/pyspotify/commit/fef39c275981123331e8ebdf405a626bfaeac364. The segfault indicates there's an issue with libspotify, or an issue with how pyspotify is using libspotify (which could be due to an incompatibility between the versions of each library). I'd make sure you've got the latest version of each.

Comment: i installed it with yaourt. ´find -name *pyspotify*´ gives me two results, one is a dirs named pyspotify-1.11-1 the other one is a .egg-info file with the same version number? but i had some troubles installing it, so it may be another version running... how can i check the version it tries to run...?

edit: libspotify is 12.1.103-2. Shold this cause this?

Comment: According to the pyspotify website, version 1.11 is from July 2013. The most recent version (and the one documented on their site) is 2.0.0a1. If you're going to stick with the older version, you need to use the old documentation, too: http://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/v1.x-develop/

Comment: it seems like there's no support for 2.0.0a1 at armv6 yet, at least there's no package installer. so right now i'm stuck with 1.11. is there some compatibility error with this version and libspotify 12.1.103-2? due to the package installer for pyspotify it said "allready installed" for each one required package so it should work..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of pyspotify here :-)

dano is right: It seems like you're reading the v2.x docs and using v1.x. v2.x is a full rewrite with different and  hopefully a lot simpler APIs to work with, so it's imperative that you use the docs that matches the version you code against:

- latest v2.x release: http://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/
- v2.0.0b1 docs: http://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/v2.0.0b1/
- v1.11 docs: http://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/v1.11/

At this point, I'd recommend using v2.x for all new applications. The v2.x API is easier to work with, works on more Python versions, covers the full libspotify API, and is actively maintained. The first beta, v2.0.0b1, was released yesterday. The final v2.0.0 release is hopefully just a few weeks away.

If you want to run pyspotify v2.x on Arch right away, you can install libspotify using yaourt:

```
sudo yaourt -S libspotify
```

Install the pyspotify build dependencies using pacman:

```
sudo pacman -S base-devel
```

And then install the latest pyspotify beta release using pip (either in a virtualenv or using sudo):

```
pip install --pre pyspotify
```

The `--pre` flag is required until pyspotify 2.0.0 final is released.

For more details, see http://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/.

pyspotify v2.x will probably appear in AUR shortly after final release.

Comment: Does the v2.x verison does not support python 2? When i try to run it with python2 i get "No module named spotify", but on python3 i at least get other errors :)

Comment: pyspotify v2.x works on CPython 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 as well as PyPy 2.1 and 2.2.